# I don't know how to understand this sentence ' it seems inconceivable that at least one of these planets does not have a life form on it'

Tags: negation

the full context is like this:

However,when we look at the 100 billion stars in our galaxy(the Milky Way),and 100 billion galaxies in the observable Universe,it seems inconceivable that at least one of these planets does not have a life form on it;in fact,the best educated guess we can make ,using the little we do know about the conditions for cabon-based life,leads us to estimate that perhaps one in 100,000 stars might have a life-bearing planet orbiting it.

someone says that 'at least one of these planets does not have a life form on it' means 'no planet has a life form on it ', but I can't understand why,to me, it means 'more than one planet have no life on it'

Comment: Source? This seems to be a translation of a Chinese text, or perhaps the opposite. Poor construction, in any case.

Comment: it is reading passage2 of Test1 in Cambridge English IELTS 9

Comment: I cannot believe (it seems inconceivable) that some planet (at least one of these planets) does not have a life form on it = It **must be** that one or more **planets have life** on them.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Thank you Yosef !your paraphrase is helpful! Did you paraphrase the sentence without a blink of an eye?I mean is the meaning of the sentence easy and direct to you when you read it?

Comment: Yes, the meaning of the sentence is clear, but it did take a second reading to paraphrase without too many changes. If you make too many changes, people don't see *how did you get this from that?*

Answer (score 2):

The writer failed to say what they meant. No wonder you have trouble understanding the sentence.

The idea the writer states is that because there are so many planets, one would think that *at least one* must have life on it. (The writer certainly doesn't go so far as to suggest that every one of those planets has life on it.)

As [Elliot implied](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/557182), after the words "It seems inconceivable" there comes the negation of that idea which the writer expects to think about all those planets. The trouble is that the writer hasn't correctly expressed the negation of that idea. The passage would be better phrased:

"... it seems inconceivable that none of these planets has a life form on it ..."

Comment: Yes, given the enormous amount of planets, I know the author wants to express that some planets must statistically have life on it , but I don't understand why he use such structure as  be+inconceivable that at least one of sth+not blablabla, is this a special writing style in English,or just the author's personal preference. and I am also wondering whether the meaning of this sentence is easy and direct for English native to understand

Comment: Also, the phrasing "at least one ... does not have ..." is confusing.  Better would be "none ... has ..."  There is similar discussion in this forum concerning the confusing phrasing "all ... are not ..."

Answer (score 0):

The trick is inconceivable.

The fact is the phrase you, quite rightly, have trouble with is preceded by "inconceivable". This usage negates the phrase following. The phrase without the negative in front is clearly wrong since we on earth have a few forms of life and are not excluded in his enumerations.

A clearer version would be;

"It seems impossible that at least one of these planets does not have a life form on it" some of it intelligent.